# Getting dinged for 'not an answer' when I think I'm providing a specific answer

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-answers

In re: [Who is the author of Sefer Shoftim (Judges)?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/82621/who-is-the-author-of-sefer-shoftim-judges/82634)

The OP asked for the views of 'secular scholars'. I believe that my question is an accurate, brief, summary of their views, based on several scholarly works. I see that I've got a pending delete vote and a critical comment 'not an answer'.

Could someone expand on the complaint? Do you require the footnotes to make this a valid answer? I could probably come up with book titles by dredging my history of Amazon purchases.

I hope it's not a view that secular views aren't wanted. Look, I rarely post here, as the culture is clearly more traditional than I am. But the OP specifically asked in this case.

Comment: Remember that a single user could have flagged it. Don't assume that the decision was based on site policy, or community consensus.

Comment: I don't know what happened here, but I think the question had a somewhat misleading paragraph -- some might have read the passage that stated "*I'd also be curious to know what secular scholars would answer to this question. However I am mainly concerned with what Jewish tradition believes*" as "It'd be cool if I could get that, but I'm not asking for it right now," which could technically make an answer that focused *solely* on secular sources NAA. I don't really have an opinion; this is just a theory. Hopefully the flagger(s?) and reviewers will speak up and explain themselves.

Comment: Given the many non-constructive comments, which clutter the exchange and prevent people from reading comments of quality,  I think points down on comments is necessary. While we're on the topic, points down for questions is IMHO ridiculous. Someone is looking for information, why not help him? If the question is really unworthy it will draw no attention and die on its own, zero points speaks for itself. The way it is now, if the first few users don't like it (for whatever reason), it will get downgraded and not receive any attention.